# How to achieve Line Feed (\n) and Carriage Return (\r) with char(13)+char(10)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
  DECLARE @name1 VARCHAR(20),
    @name2 VARCHAR(20)

    SET @name1 = 'Hello'
    SET @name2 ='World'
    SELECT @name1 + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + @name2
```

Reslut is

```
Hello  World
```

But I want Result Like this

```
Hello  
World
```

char(13)+Char(10) not working for Line Feed (\n) and Carriage Return (\r)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to `Result to Text` to see the result in new line i.e, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and then execute the query.

**Output:**

```
------------------------------------------
Hello
World

(1 row(s) affected)
```

You can find [this good reference](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/381955/sql-server-management-studio-should-show-new-lines-in-records) to see why I say it is not possible:

> When using the results to grid option, we use the standard Windows
>   grid control to display the results. This grid control treats each
>   cell value as a plain text and hence the new line characters are
>   ignored. The Save as function when executed from the results section
>   just takes the content from the grid as it is and hence the newline is
>   not found in the new file created from the grid. However if you use
>   the results to text option or the results to file the new line
>   characters are retained. SSMS is not really intended to be a reporting
>   tool, so we are unable to spend much time on the result formatting,
>   especially if some work arounds exist like mentioned above.

Comment: But i want this result in gridview not in text view

Comment: @FarhatUllah:- That is not possible inside a grid view. You have change it to Text view to see the result in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Table Result will not show newline. Print it like below.

```
   DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
PRINT ('SELECT FirstLine AS FL ' +@NewLineChar + 'SELECT SecondLine AS SL' )
```

Comment: But this is our requirement. how to achieve this? any alternate solution instead of text view?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name1 VARCHAR(20),
@name2 VARCHAR(20)

SET @name1 = 'Hello'
SET @name2 ='World'
SELECT @name1 
Union
select  @name2
```

Try with this...